# Python files won't run outside certain folder

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, interpreter

Why do my python files not run outside certain folders? If I create a new python file on my desktop it will not run, instead it will ask me to select an interpreter. I will select one inside a folder but it still does not run.

[image: Working files status with 3.10.5 version]

[image: file on desktop that does not work: "select interpreter"]

[image: I will click on the highlighted and recommended workspace level but nothing will happen]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of vscode is only effective for the current workspace. If you want to run a file outside the workspace, please use the folder containing the file as a new workspace.

My suggestion is that you put your code in a separate folder and use this folder as your workspace. This facilitates your future management and maintenance of your code environment.

You can refer to the [document of workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces) in vscode for more details.